# C# Sum of numberfields (Static and dynamic) less than 100

Tags: javascript, c#, listener, ext.net

I have 3 static `numberfields` and I am creating some `numberfields` more in `CodeBehind`. What I want is to limit the `sum` of the values of all `numberfields` to 100.

Here are the static `numberfields`:

```
<ext:NumberField ID="numS1" runat="server" MinValue="0" MaxValue="100" FieldLabel="numS1" />                                                
<ext:NumberField ID="numS2" runat="server" MinValue="0" MaxValue="100" FieldLabel="numS2" />                                          
<ext:NumberField ID="numS3" runat="server" MinValue="0" MaxValue="100" FieldLabel="numS3" />
```

And here are the dynamic `numberfields` created in code behind:

```
foreach (var v in visits)
{
    NumberField nf = new NumberField();
    nf.ID = v.VISID + "num";
    nf.MaxValue = 100;
    nf.MinValue = 0;
    nf.FieldLabel = v.VISID;
    PerVisitFS.Items.Add(nf);
    nf.Render();
}
```

What I have tried to do is to use a `hidden` field `#{sum100}` and for the `dynamic` fields create a `listener` on `blur` event:

```
nf.Listeners.Blur.Handler = "#{sum100}.setValue(Number(this.getValue()) + Number(#{sum100}.getValue()));";
```

And on the `Before` event of the `click` of a button I added this code:

```
Before="#{sum100}.setValue(Number(#{sum100}.getValue()) + Number(#{numS1}.getValue()) + Number(#{numS2}.getValue()) + Number(#{nums#}.getValue())); 
if ( #{sum100}.getValue() > 100)
{ alert('sum is > 100 : ' + #{sum100}.getValue()); 
     #{sum100}.setValue(0); 
     return false;
}
else
{alert('sum is : ' + #{sum100}.getValue())}">
```

But the problem with this approach is that when I enter some values for the first time it works, but if I try to update a `dynamic` field then it will calculate the sum with only the updated `numberfield` and the `static` ones without the other `dynamic` ones.

This happens because the `blur` event is not triggered in the not-changed `dynamic` `numberfields`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put that on the "Before" click do that:

```
            var numOfNumFields = 3; //increase as necessary, it could came from a hidden field 

            var sum = 0;
            for ( var i = 0; i< numOfNumFields;i++){

               sum += Ext.getCmp('numS'+i).getValue();
            }
            if (sum > 100)
            { 
                alert('sum is > 100 : ' + sum); 
                return false
            }
            else
            {
                alert('sum is : ' + sum);
                return true;
            }
```